# rsync from external vfat disk to local ext4 yields VASTLY different sizes

Tags: filesystems, rsync, hard-disk, ext4, vfat

I found an older external hd I want to reuse for something else. I was doing an rsync of it to a NAS I run over the network but it was taking ages.

So I decided to rsync to my local drive first (SSD) and do the final backup to NAS later.

I ran `rsync -avvz --progress /media/ubuntu/9AB4-7DB9/ubuntu/ bak`.
This seems to have terminated fine.

But when I compare the two dirs for their sizes, they are VASTLY different.

```
du -kh bak
29G bak

du -kh /media/ubuntu/9AB4-7DB9/ubuntu/
56G /media/ubuntu/9AB4-7DB9/ubuntu/
```

How is this possible?
I first assumed that the `vfat` file system might be to blame - but to this extent? I can't believe it to be nearly doubling the size

I also thought it could be the `-z` compress option of `rsync`, but that should only compress during transfer as I understand:
`-z, --compress              compress file data during the transfer`

Any ideas?
I am baffled, and just want to make sure my backup was complete. Thanks,

Comment: Sort of, the answer below is clearer to understand IMO

Comment: The answer in the link actually covers all possible ways files can change size on copy, but my answer narrowed it down to the most likely of these in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The du command measures file size in blocks, not bytes.
Since vfat and ext4 use completely different block sizes, a size change of 2x or even 8x would not be even slightly surprising.

ext4 typically uses 4k blocks but both ext4 and vfat use a variable block size set when the disk is formatted.  vfat supports logical block sizes between 512b and 32k; ext4 supports block sizes between 1k and 4k.

If it is an old disk, it could be 512b blocks or maybe 2k, depending on disk size and properties.  If you have a lot of files that are below 2k, each of those could double in size on copy to a 4k block size ext4.

Comment: Oh very interesting. So this indeed seems the case here. I am assuming all my backup was successful then. 

Is there a command with which I can check on the actual block size(s), in order to fully verify this issue?

Comment: You could try creating a one byte file and use du to see how big it is.

Comment: For the records, I created a file: `echo "hi" > /path/to/file` for each file system, then called `du /path/to/file`  for each. My `ext4` reported 4k, the `vfat` one reported 32k. I then couldn't resist, copied the file over from vfat to ext4, ran `du` again and it "magically" was 4k. There we are.